# How to commit specific changes in git

Tags: command, git

I renamed a interface (IMoo to IKey) and a class file (Moo to Key). After that I created a method (blob()) in the class file and created the implementation in the interface. How can I commit these two changes seperatly in git?

So that the first commit only contains the renaming changes and the second commit contains the method and the implementation in the interface.

Comment: Just do separate `git add` followed by `git commit` operations.

Comment: What is your exact state and intent? What is your git history? Do you have a local/ remote commit about that.

Comment: Look at `git add --patch`, but, as aydinugur said, it is not clear the state and intent. You should also post you `git status` maybe?

Comment: The state of the last commit is before the renaming. My intent is to make 2 seperate commits as outlined above.

Comment: Did you use `git mv` to rename the file? With this command, git will track all the content to the new file.

Comment: Stage only the changes you want to commit, and then make a commit.

Comment: @GuilhermeM - No, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far easier to commit changes separately as you make them than to try to separate them out after they're all combined together.

That means it may be easier to re-do the first change, commit it, and then re-apply the full changes, than to mess with things like interactive staging.

*Redo Approach*

So for example, you could save and set aside your current changes

```
git stash
```

Then redo the rename operation, which should be straightforward.  Then something like

```
git add .
git commit -m "rename class and interface"
```

Next get your full changes back.  To avoid possible conflicts, I'd do something like

```
git checkout HEAD^
git stash pop
git reset --mixed HEAD@{1}
```

And now you should see the rename in your history, and the remaining changes in your work tree ready to be staged and committed.

*No Redo Approach*

The above does assume you can easily redo the class renaming, either because it's a small change (small codebase, or at least not a lot of references throughout the codebase that refer to the affected class and interface) or because your IDE will do it for you (which, if not, you might want to think about using nicer development tools).  But what if you had a more complex change?

Ideally you could say `git add -i` to start an interactive staging session, and work your way through the prompts to specify that the class name change is in, but the new method is out.  They should be separate change hunks, so ok...

But the problem is, depending on your programming language and code layout, you may have renamed the file when you renamed the class.  The interactive staging tools aren't good at dealing with that.

So in that case, you could go back to the previous commit, *just* rename the files and commit that, then restore your changes on top of the new commit, then do an interactive staging operation.  But by the time you do all that, you've done almost all the steps of my original suggestion, plus the interactive rebase, and you'd still have an extra/broken/presumably-unwanted commit in the history (which you'd probably want to squash)... so what's the point?

Well, if for some reason you want to try it this way, see the `git add` documentation related to `-i` and `-p` options.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add